# SQL WHERE multiple columns

Tags: sql

I'm trying to implement a query to find the cheapest package to Spain.

I'm having a problem with my 'Where h.location = 'Spain'. I need the where function to facilitate my other columns too. For example: - e.location, t.location and f.location. Which would all ='Spain'

```
        SELECT p.*, (h.totalCost + e.totalCost + t.totalCost + f.totalCost) as    'Total Package Cost' FROM Package p
         INNER JOIN hotels h ON h.hotelId = p.hotelId
         INNER JOIN excursions e ON e.excursionId = p.excursionId
         INNER JOIN transport t ON t.transportId = p.transportId
         INNER JOIN flight f ON f.flightId = p.flightId
  WHERE h.location = 'Spain'

  ORDER BY (h.totalCost + e.totalCost + t.totalCost + f.totalCost) ASC
```

How to I go about this?

Comment: That many tables I would usually join in a common table expression and then select off that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend doing it this way

```
WHERE h.location = 'Spain'
 AND e.location = h.location
 AND t.location = h.location
 AND f.location = h.location
```

so if you want to change the variable of "Spain"  (which I'm assuming will be a variable) you would only need to include in one place in your query.

Comment: Note, a few more comments about your query.  You don't really need to state `inner join` each time;  this is generally assumed.  You can just use `join` such as `JOIN hotels h ON h.hotelId = p.hotelId`.  Also, since you created an alias for your variable, in your order by statement, you can just use `order by 'Total Package Cost' ` ; you don't need to recalculate this variable.

Answer (score 2):

if they all have to equal "Spain" then just add them to the WHERE clause with AND

```
  WHERE h.location = 'Spain'
     AND e.location = 'Spain'
     AND t.location = 'Spain'
     AND f.location = 'Spain'
```